# Datepicker c использованием JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Здравствуйте пытаюсь установить на свой сайт datepicker с полем input , при нажатии на которое должен вылазить календарик, но почему то у меня появляется только поле input с предустановленной датой. Подскажите что не так?

```
   <script src="js/jquery_ui_datepicker/jquery_ui_datepicker.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery_ui_datepicker/i18n/ui.datepicker-ru.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery_ui_datepicker/timepicker_plug/timepicker.js"></script>
   <link href="js/jquery_ui_datepicker/timepicker_plug/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <link href="js/jquery_ui_datepicker/smothness/jquery_ui_datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <input class="datetime" value="2008-08-23 10:45:00" id="starttime"/>
   <script  type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('input.datetime').datetime({
    userLang : 'ru'
    });
   });
   </script>
```

Ссылка на исходник
http://xdan.ru/down/file/12
И на сайт с уроком
http://xdan.ru/ispolzuem-datepicker-iz-jquery-ui.html

Answer (score 1):

сделай так

```
jQuery('#starttime').datetimepicker({
lang:'ru',
timepicker:false,
format:'Y-m-d',
value:'2008-08-23 10:45:00'
});
```

ну у меня во всяком случае так.